# How to fix the Bottom Nav Bar when working with recyclerView?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-recyclerview, bottomnavigationview

I am designing a page with a Recycler View and a Bottom Nav Bar but the problem is that the bottom nav bar is hidden at the bottom and when I scroll up the recycler view, the bottom nav bar is visible. I have tried every possible way I can think of, I have used Coordinator layout, linear layout, relative layout, and frame layout but in every scenario, the output is the same.

Below is my xml code with Constraint Layout that I have recently tried and still the issue is same.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.BiteBackCommunityFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewCommunity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: This is the output I am getting]

Please help me as I am trying to solve this problem since yesterday. and by the way, I am designing this UI in a fragment.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using recycler view to cover entire constraint layout, you should add a nav host fragment and then add further views like recycler view as a child of that. Try using coordinator layout with a nav host fragemnt and bottom navigation, something like this :

This an an example of how you can use a nav host fragment, along with a toolbar and bottom nativation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bot_nav_bar_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_coordinator">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_container"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
                tools:ignore="FragmentTagUsage" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:menu="@menu/options_menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:elevation="15sp"
                app:hideOnScroll="true"
                app:title="Login"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bot_nav_bar_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:elevation="15sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bot_nav_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="true"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="auto"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your time but this is also not working, tried this and got the same output screen as above. My bottom nav view is always hidden.